# Proving the sample variance has a chi squared critical value

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory, probability-distributions, proof-verification

Let $X_1, . . . , X_n$ be independent normal observations with means $µ = 0$ and variances $σ^2$. For testing the null hypothesis $H_0 : σ^2 = 1$ versus the alternative $H_a : σ^2 > 1$ show that the likelihood ratio test is $$\dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i^2>\dfrac{k}{n}$$ where the critical value $k$ is the $\alpha$ critical value for the $\chi^2_n$ distribution. You can use the fact that $$\hat{\sigma^2}=\dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i^2$$

Basically I found the likelihood ratio which I got was $$T=2[\dfrac{-n}{2}ln(\hat{\sigma^2})-\dfrac{n}{2}+\dfrac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i^2]$$ Let $k\in\mathbb{R}$ such that 
$$T=2[\dfrac{-n}{2}ln(\hat{\sigma^2})-\dfrac{n}{2}+\dfrac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i^2]>k\geq 0$$ since we know $T\geq 0$. From here I get $$\dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^2-ln(\hat{\sigma^2})-1>\dfrac{k}{n}$$. The only way I can establish this relationship is by seeing that since $T\geq 0$ then it follows that $$\dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^2>ln(\hat{\sigma^2})+1\implies\dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^2>\dfrac{k}{n}\implies \sum_{i=1}^nx_i^2>k $$. Now under the null hypothesis it follows $X_1,..,X_n$~$N(0,1)$ and iid (Cochrans Theorem). Therefore it follows $\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^2$~$\chi_n^2$. We can let $k=\chi_{\alpha,n}^2$ for any specified $\alpha$.

Would this be correct? Thanks. This was the only way I could see doing this problem.

Comment: Its correct then since im getting likes?